# How does Git keep track of branch state despite being unable to connect to my git server

Tags: git, github, gitlab

My company uses a VPN to limit access to the corporate network. Our Git server sits on this corporate network, and as such requires the VPN for access.

Recently, when I checked out master locally I got the following output:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 33 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

However, when attempting to pull master, I got the following, as I was not connected to the VPN:

```
squishman@squishman-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~/SkyATF$ git pull origin master
ssh: Could not resolve hostname [REDACTED]: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My question is, how can Git know how far behind my local master is, if it cannot connect to the git server?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, how can Git know how far behind my local master is, if it cannot connect to the git server?

It doesn't.

It knows how far you *were* behind, the *last time your Git got an update* from the other Git.  A successful `git fetch` updates things and you'll get an answer that is merely seconds out of date, instead of minutes.

The count you see is the result of comparing the branch's commit (as found via `git rev-parse HEAD`) against the branch's upstream's commit (`git rev-parse HEAD@{upstream}`).  Running `git rev-list --count --left-right HEAD...HEAD@{u}` will get you the numbers for ahead and behind respectively.  (This three-dot syntax and the `--count --left-right` are a bit tricky to explain, although a combination of [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) and [the `git rev-list` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) will get you there.)

Comment: This is a fundamental concept in git. Almost all git commands are local other than `push` and `fetch` (and `pull` which is just a `fetch` + `merge|rebase`, and also some expert-level commands.) that do talk to a remote. @DVukajlo make sure you fully understand it. Talk to your colleagues/team leader/mentor, do some git tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

By `git remote -v` you can get the list of remotes (if you have more then one).

By `git branch -av` you get a detailed list of branches and the related remote, so keep in mind that a branch is indirectly associated to a remote URI.